# How to place a Loader on the screen while an API action is being performed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show a loader when a form is submitted to the server so that there isn't another submission of the same form until and unless the API sends back a response. I have tried something like the below code but it just doesn't seem to work as the Circular Progress indicator seems to not show up and rather, the screen remains as it is until the server sends back a response. As a result of this, the user gets confused as to whether or not their requests got submitted, and in the process, they end up posting the same form another time only to find out later that their were multiple submissions. I will include snippets of the code that has the `CircularProgressIndicator()` to prevent another submission and the widget that has the API call code.

```
bool isSelected = false;
  isSelected
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: AppButtonStyle(
                    label: 'Submit',
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {     //This is the key of the Form that gets submitted
                        setState(() {
                          isSelected = true;
                        });
                        List<String> date = [
                          dateFormat.format(_dateTimeStart!).toString(),
                          dateFormat.format(_dateTimeEnd!).toString()
                        ];
                        Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                          'leave_type': _selectedItem,
                          'dates': date,
                          'description': add
                        };
                        if (kDebugMode) {
                          print('DATA: $data');
                        }
                        Provider.of<LeaveViewModel>(context, listen: false)
                            .postLeaveRequests(data, context)     //This here makes the API call
                            .then((value) {
                          setState(() {
                            isSelected = false;
                            _textController.clear();
                            _dateTimeStart = null;
                            _dateTimeEnd = null;
                          });
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

The API module:

```
class LeaveViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final leaveRepository = LeaveRequestRepository();

  Future<void> postLeaveRequests(dynamic data, BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String authToken = localStorage.getString('token').toString();

    leaveRepository.requestLeave(authToken, data).then((value) {
      print('LEAVEEEEEE: $value');
      Flushbar(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white),
        // margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 100, 0),
        title: 'Leave Request Submitted',
        message: value.data.toString()
      ).show(context);
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      Flushbar(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white),
        // margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 100, 0),
        title: 'Leave Request Failed',
        message: error.toString()
      ).show(context);
    });
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Also, I'm open to the concept of using `easy_loader 2.0.0` instead of `CicularProgressIndicator()` and would be very glad to read suggestions about it's usage in my code.

Comment: onPressed: () async { ------  await Provider.of<LeaveViewModel>(context, listen: false)
                            .postLeaveRequests(data, context)     //This here makes the API call
                            .then((value..........

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code seems to be that you define isSelected in your build method. Every time you call setState, the build method is called to regenerate the widgets. And with each new call isSelected gets false as initial value. Define isSelected as class variable, so that it is not always on false.

The more elegant solution would be to work with a FutureBuilder

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html